# Anonymous C# function with Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How do I create an anonymous function type?  I've used 'void' as a filler type:

```
private void afte(string filtr,void parse) {

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
        new Uri("xx.com"));
    request.BeginGetResponse(r => {
        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.EndGetResponse(r);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
            var response = reader.ReadToEnd();

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                parse(response);
            }));
        }
    }, request);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `parse` a delegate that only accepts a string parameter (`response`) with a void return (or rather, without a return value)?

Use `Action<string>`:

```
private void afte(string filtr, Action<string> parse) {
```

Comment: private void parse(string ss){}

Comment: Must your `afte()` method need to conform to any interfaces or delegates itself? If not you can just give it one parameter (`string filtr`).